# How does EIP-4844 make rollups 100x cheaper?

Tags: eip, sharding, danksharding, eip-4844

I have been seeing [claims](https://twitter.com/jessepollak/status/1582784133121859585) that proto-danksharding is going to make rollups 10-100x cheaper at various [sources](https://twitter.com/pseudotheos/status/1504457560396468231). I understand how it would be ~10x cheaper: right now, rollups use calldata and it costs about 16 gas/byte. After EIP-4844, rollups can use blobs, which uses data_gas and costs as little as [1 gas/byte](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4844). This would at most make it 16x cheaper though.

Where exactly does this 100x come from? Is 100x referring to full danksharding? Are my sources outdated?

Comment: when was this thing released? I don't see this new kind of transaction called "blob" transaction in current sources: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/2a2b0419fb966c54fb86b17bbccea743a45b4d2a/core/types/transaction.go#L44

Comment: Where did you get the 1 gas/byte number from? Can't find in the EIP, did you compute it somehow?

Comment: It's the MIN_DATA_GASPRICE param

Comment: The new Transaction type is here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/v1.13.14/core/types/transaction.go

Answer (score 0):

EIP-4844 enables rollups to bundle multiple transactions into a single transaction and then batch them onto the root chain. This reduces the number of transactions that need to be broadcast to the root chain, thus reducing the cost of running rollups by up to 100 times.

Comment: Rollups already do that, today.